# Git repository server I can host locally

Tags: git

Does anyone know of a Git repository browser that I can host on my own server similar to GitHub?  I really like the GitHub browsing and history interface, but my favorite part is the network graph.  I'd like to run something like this to see the branches and merges in my own repositories.

Comment: When I googled for "git repo browser", this is the top result. It's ashame that the answer doesn't mention gitk, but now I realized you're not really asking what I thought you were asking. I edited the title to better reflect what you're really asking.

Comment: "I'd like to run something like this to see the branches and merges in my own repositories." If this is the main requirement, gitk certainly does the job.

Comment: I don't know why this question is closed. THis is infact a very important question

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can download and setup [Gitorious](http://gitorious.org). It's free open-source git-hosting software. I'm not sure about all the features it has so take a closer look, it might be the right thing for you.

Updated January 2016:

[Gitlab](https://gitlab.com) is becoming the defacto standard for self-hosted Github clones.

[Gogs](https://github.com/gogits/gogs) is a simpler clone that could work well for smaller projects.

Comment: Why is "Gitlab becoming the standard" for clones?  Any sources/proof?

Answer (score 4):

Paying for github private hosting seems the quickest way. The network viewer is totally proprietary.

There are patches over on [repo.or.cz](http://repo.or.cz/) that [add a similar interface as gitk to the vanilla gitweb](http://repo.or.cz/w/git/gitweb.git) front end. It is, or at least was when I tried it, a complete pain to set up but is doable for your own projects.

The output is really like gitk, like it or loathe it, so if you are used to that it is familiar at least. Here is the [graphical log of git itself](http://repo.or.cz/git-browser/by-commit.html?r=git.git).

Answer (score 4):

If you use MacOS, try [GitX](http://gitx.frim.nl/).

Answer (score 2):

Another option you have these days is http://gitlab.org/

It is open source and free to use. It is based on ruby on rails though, so it might not be available on your average php hosting service.

Answer (score 1):

Git comes with a built-in web view: [gitweb](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Gitweb). You probably have it already installed as /usr/share/gitweb or somewhere similar.

Answer (score 1):

**[codeBeamer](http://www.intland.com/products/codebeamer/overview/) can be installed on your very own server, as an "intranet GitHub".**

It does everything GitHub does: Git repository hosting, workflows and pull requests, issue tracking, wiki, binariy downloads, etc. and more. It doesn't actually have the network graph, as this feature is considered a "nice to have", rather than a "must have" feature among our users.

(Disclaimer: we develop this commercial product.)

Answer (score 0):

[Gitblit](http://gitblit.com) is an open-source, integrated, pure Java Git server, viewer, and repository manager for small workgroups.  The current version (0.5.1) does not support anything like network graph, but its a quick and easy-to-use tool for hosting and browsing git repositories.