# How can I host Git repositories and manage my content-hosting myself?

Tags: git, repository, gitolite

Things such as Github, Bitbucket, DropBox -- manages the content-hosting such as tickets and repo -hosting (DB not tickets but can be used to store repos). I want a solution where I manage myself the content-hosting of thing such as Git -repositories and tickets.

> **Trial 0: trying to tune Git, too time-consuming**
>
> > I followed the instructions
> >     [here](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server-Getting-Git-on-a-Server)
> >     but some difficulties then I followed a lot of other tutorials with
> >     much more difficulties. I got cloning with `"git clone --bare xxx
> >     xxx.git; cd xxx; git update-server-info"` working but unable to push
> >     things with `"--shared"`, got fed up to this kind of manual hacks.
> >     There is too much material, too much irrelevant material and too much
> >     outdated material.

I repeat I want to do the content-hosting myself. So how can I host my git repos?

**Perhaps related**

> 1. [Git repository server I can host locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/722765/is-there-a-git-repository-server-i-can-host-locally)
> 2. [Recommendation for code hosting of personal projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109055/recommendation-for-code-hosting-of-personal-projects)

Comment: have you looked here: http://windows.github.com/

Comment: @yasouser Even better may be http://bitbucket.org. They allow for unlimited free private repositories (with a maximum number of collaborators of course).

Comment: @Michael: thank you for the notice, I clarified the q when I realized what you mean -- yes I want to do the content-hosting myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're running a Linux server an option is to use Git + SSH.

**On The Server**

1. Create a user account called `git` which has permissions over your main git project directory. This is useful for allowing all collaborators to push on shared projects.
2. Add the RSA public key for each of your client machines to the `authorized_keys` file on the server. (You can generate a private-public key pair using `ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096` on most Linux distributions.)
3. Create a new bare repository for your project as the `git` user. `git init myproject --bare`

**On the Client**

1. Turn on private key authentication by enabling the `IdentifyFile` in your `ssh_config`.
2. Clone the bare repository. `git clone git@<server>:/var/git/myproject`
3. Make your changes.
4. Commit the changes and push them back to the remote repo. `git push origin master`

If you need more specific instructions (such as the exact commands to create a user account) checkout the official [Pro Git](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server) book.

Comment: +1 well done, clean and well-written! I like your way of cutting out the extras such as gitolite, redmine, github, bitbucket, dropbox -- better to outline basics clearly.

Answer (score 2):

I would go with Gitolite (manages the permissions) [here](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/) and Redmine (manages the workflow over many repos) [here](http://www.redmine.org/). If you have no need for permission -management, please, go with Michael's solution. If you do not need to manage many repos, forget Redmine (useful with many repositories). The stuff here contain the same stuff as in Michael's answer but in third-party sites and some additions that you may need when your projects expand.

**0. Git + SSH -keypair (Please, see the Michael's answer and below some outlining.)**

> If you are unable to do this, do not proceed forward -- this method
>   shows the basic way of using bare -repos to content-host your repos.
>   It takes some 2 minutes' time to do it, simply:
>
> > **On server**
> >
> > ```
> > $ git init --bare test.git
> > ```
> >
> > **On client**
> >
> > ```
> > $ eval `ssh-agent`
> > $ ssh-add ~/your_auhorized_key_in_server
> > $ git clone something@IP:test.git
> > ```

**1. Gitolite (managing perms of a team with different skills)**

> 1. excellent step-by-step tutorial [here](https://sites.google.com/site/senawario/home/gitolite-tutorial)
>      (notice the `"~/.ssh/authorized_keys"` -file must have only gitolite -user)
> 2. check out repository -addition/removal [here](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/qi.html), yes it is that
>      simple -- you just configure the config -file and then `"$ git add .;
>      git commit -m "new repos, old dead"` and `"$ git push"`
> 3. `"$ ssh gitolite@xxx.yy.112.239 info"` shows you the configuration
>
>    ```
>            hello hhh, this is gitolite@ip-10-xxx-xx-203 running gitolite3 v3.03-29-g3c0f177 on git 1.7.4.5
>
>             R W    helloworld
>             R      gitolite-admin
>             R W    testing
>    ```
> 4. Cloning a repository under gitolite
>
>    `$ git clone gitolite@176.34.112.239:helloworld`

**2. Redmine/Trac/etc (managing workflow over repos in a central GUI place)**

> Instructions
>   [here](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineInstall) for Redmine
>   and be sure not to clone the unstable development branch in Github.
>   You need to download some stable archieve. However, I would probably go with 
>   Trac, comparison [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5881578/trac-vs-redmine).
>   Redmine was some Rails -hack and unstable master -branch does not sound good.

**3. Ticgit/etc (managing tickets without thirdparty dependencies)**

> Bremner outlined this issue [here](http://www.cs.unb.ca/~bremner/blog/posts/git-issue-trackers/) but notice this ticket [here](https://github.com/jeffWelling/ticgit/issues/57), things still in very bad shape. General thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11218069/version-control-for-tickets).

Comment: Just a suggestion but you might want to add a link to [Git on the Server - Gitolite](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server-Gitolite). This appears to be part of the official git-scm documentation.

Comment: Substitutes for Trac/Redmine, you may want to consult also Gerrit/Gitslave -- more [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11253615/git-a-tool-to-manage-and-to-structure-projects-in-the-version-control).